# Passing multiple parameters to an Angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a chart component in Angular 2.

So far it receives an array of tuples and displays this data as a line chart.

The parent component uses the chart like this:

```
<line-chart [values]="myFirstLineValues"></line-chart>
```

Now I want to display to lines in the same chart. I could add two input parameter (like `values1` and `values2`), but maybe later I want to display *n* lines.

So I was thinking of having an array of arrays as input parameter. This would work. But when I want to individually style the lines I would need more arrays of properties for the styling as well. This doesn't seem to be a very elegant way.

I was hoping for a solution like this (pseudo syntax I just made up):

```
<line-chart>
    <line [value]="myFirstLineValues"/>
    <line [value]="mySecondLineValues" />
</line-chart>
```

Later I could add styling for the lines with special properties of each line (or even passing a CSS class in for each line).

Is this or something similar possible in Angular 2? Or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the problem with the solution you're hoping for?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to pass multiple arrays of values to a chart component. I could use an array of arrays, but something like the example above would be more readable to me. Plus I could add properties to the line elements to define the rendering (like strokeWidth, color) or better the name of a css class for the individual line.

Comment: With your approach ("was hoping for")  your are not passing anything to the component. This is just to projecting `<line>` elements to be shown as children of `<line-chart>`. I think array of arrays is the way to go. I find `<line-chart [values]="[myFirstLineValues, mySecondLineValues]"></line-chart>` simple enough.

Comment: The example was just something I made up, how I could imagine passing the values to the component (having no knowledge of the right way to do this in angular (I'm just starting to learn angular).

Comment: I see. As mentioned I would go for array of arrays.

Comment: @Alessio Angular 2 is no longer referred to as AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain an array of object, where object is `{style: string, data: []}`, making your input of type: `{style: string, data: []}[]`.

This gives you the array of arrays approach, and associates a style with each set of data.